# Meteor: How to use object names including dashes in Spacebars

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

Didn't find the answer anywhere, but maybe one of you knows it.

I'm getting back data from http.call('GET'), I can use the data correctly in
Spacebars like

```
{{anydata.specificdata}}
```

but have no chance to use data w/ object names containing dashes like

```
{{anydata.specific-data}}
```

I tried

```
{{anydata.'specific-data'}}
```

, but this does not work either.
As I'm retrieving a lot of different data I would like to avoid to create helpers for every field containing dashes.

Does anyone know how I could handle something like

```
{{anydata.specific-data}?
```

Thanks for any answer that helps.

Have Fun!

Comment: What about `{{anydata['specific-data']}}`?

Comment: `{{anydata('specific-data')}}` it should work with `()`

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I tried both options, first one doesn't output anything, the second one throws a Meteor server error...

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer on a meteor form: https://forums.meteor.com/t/dash-character-in-spacebars/2885

I ran into a similar problem. I had a json object with a dash in a the variable name. In order to call an object with a dash, the following is done:

```
{{some.json.object.[with-a-dash]}}
```

Note the . before the open bracket and no quotes (single or double) around the dash named item.

Comment: that's actually the one and only!

Answer (score 0):

on the HTTP success callback map the data object properties from dash to camelcase, then use your new object.

Comment: Working on this, will come back with results, difficult, as the input object is always a mixture of objects and arrays, but I'm moving further,..

Comment: haven't tried it, but this exists... https://www.npmjs.com/package/camelcase-keys

Answer (score 0):

Some days offline behind...

I did not find a nice solution (due to the unexpectable combination of arrays and objects in the htpp result) but a working one:

I use EJSON.stringify() to stringify the http-result and replace the dashes in the object keys using a regular expression, then use EJSON.parse() to make it an object again. Done.

Not very elegant but working fine and fast.

Have Fun!