# Meteor JSON Method and Call in template

Tags: json, meteor

I am trying to call a Meteor method with a parsed json doc to use in my template. None of my calls work and I then need advise on how to display (maybe I should save this part for another post - but any suggestions would be helpful) in template with helpers. I am new to meteor and javascript.

Json doc

```
{
"sports-content": {
    "sport-event": [{
        "event-metadata": {
            "league": "NCAA Basketball",
            "event-type": "0",
            "league-details": "NCAAB",
            "event-date-time": "12/18/2015 07:00 PM",
            "eventNum": "3000460",
            "status": "",
            "off-the-board": "False"
        },
        "team": [{
            "team-metadata": {
                "alignment": "Home",
                "nss": "526",
                "openNum": "526",
                "name": {
                    "full": "Clemson"
                }
            },
            "wagering-stats": {
                "wagering-straight-spread": {
                    "bookmaker-name": "BetOnline",
                    "active": "true",
                    "line": "1.5",
                    "money": "-110",
                    "context": "current"
                }
            },
            "team-stats": {
                "score": "0"
            }
        }, {
            "team-metadata": {
                "alignment": "Away",
                "openNum": "525",
                "nss": "525",
                "name": {
                    "full": "South Carolina"
                }
            },
            "wagering-stats": {
                "wagering-straight-spread": {
                    "bookmaker-name": "BetOnline",
                    "active": "true",
                    "line": "-1.5",
                    "money": "-110",
                    "context": "current"
                }
            },
            "team-stats": {
                "score": "0"
            }
        }]
    }],
    "sports-meta-data": {
        "doc-time": "42353.5979256944"
    }
  }
 }
```

server.js

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
 Meteor.methods({
sportsFeed:function(){
  //console.log(JSON.parse(Assets.getText('ncaab.json')));
  var feed = {};
  var feed = JSON.parse(Assets.getText("ncaab.json"));
  return feed;
}
  });

 });
```

Template.html

```
  <template name="tabsOne">
   <p>{{display}}</p>
  </template>
```

Template.js

```
Template.tabsOne.helpers({
  display: function(){
    Meteor.call('sportsFeed', function(error, result){
      if(error){
        console.log("error", error);
     }
     if(result){
       console.log('success');
     }
   });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If the json file is from your local, thinking about save it into Mongo and then publish it to the client

First, you need to create a collection called SportContent and on the server side, just make

```
SportContent.insert(JSON.parse(Assets.getText("ncaab.json")));
```

and then, do the normal publication to the client

2. If the json file is not on your local side (as in, you get it from rest call service), use `wrapAsync` to wrap the `Http.call`, then trigger the rest call and return the result. On your client side, you will get the response

Example on the server side to connect to the rest api

```
Meteor.methods({
  'updateFeed': function () {
    var httpCall  = Meteor.wrapAsync(HTTP.call);
    var result = httpCall('GET', url, {headers: headers});
    ....
  }
});
```

Comment: I am using the json doc in a local file /private to create the template pages but in the future the feed will be coming from an api that will be updated by the second. I am not sure importing it in the database is a efficient (any suggestion? also how do I insert into database easily. But has not worked yet). Right now I got it to display in the template page via a helper but I am not able to sort and manipulate it partially because the keys have hyphens ("event-metadata")

Comment: I am still trying to figure out how to use this json doc in template {{event-metadata}} does not work. Thank you for any help you can give me.

Comment: This looks good and I will accept the answer, but still am having difficulties displaying the keys in handlebars because of the hyphens. Can you give me an example of how you would implement in template.helper?

Comment: what is the problem with the hyphen ?

Comment: when i add a helper and try to access the data with {{sports-content}} or loop through the sport-event array with {{#each}}, I get errors telling me that the blaze cannot handle the "-" hyphen.

Comment: ok got it. hyphen is another problem. i never tried with the hyphen on the template before, but this link should give you a good start http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29524753/meteor-how-to-use-object-names-including-dashes-in-spacebars

Comment: Thanks, I will research futher.